# The operation cannot be completed: - Create/update: a mandatory field is not set. Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I need to create new record in 'pos.order.line' if some conditions; in 'onchange' function.

Here is my code , I got this error :

```
The operation cannot be completed: - Create/update: a mandatory field is not set. - Delete: another model requires the record being deleted. If possible, archive it instead.  Model: Point of Sale Order Lines (pos.order.line), Field: Order Ref (order_id) .
```

How can get the order_id if I don't save it yet ?

```
class PosOrder(models.Model):

    _inherit = "pos.order.line"

    @api.onchange('product_id')

    def onchange_product(self):

        if condition:

            new_pos_order_line = self.create({

                'product_id': ....,

                'price_unit': ....,

                'qty':1,

            })
```

Any help please?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but look into the [Danger Info in the official docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/orm.html#odoo.api.onchange).

Comment: Same problem with on_change ,did you find a solution ??!